# installed Arch Linux but cannot boot

Tags: arch-linux, boot, uefi, systemd-boot

I have installed Arch Linux for the first time, I have attempted to setup my UEFI boot process but must have failed somewhere, on bootup I do see the boot menu with the `Arch Linux` option but when I select it, I get a message `/vmlinuz-linux:Not Found` i.e. it can't find the kernel to boot. I've followed the instructions on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide but must have messed up somewhere.

How can I fix this?

partition layout:

```
/dev/sda1 EFI System (512M)
/dev/sda2 Linux fs (244M)
/dev/sda3 Linux fs (1M)
/dev/sda4 Linux fs (465G)
```

`/etc/fstab`:

```
#/dev/sda4  
UUID=41d8483f-0d29-4234-bf1e-3c55346b5667  /  ext4    rw,realtime,data=unordered 0 1
```

`esp` was setup in `/boot/`

**edit 1**
Oh yeah I can anytime boot from my USB thumb drive for troubleshooting...,

**edit2**
I see, my `/boot/loder/entries/arch.conf` looks like:

```
title          Arch Linux
linux          /vmlinuz-linux
initrd         /initramfs-linux.img
options        root=PARTUUID=41d8483f-0d29-4234-bf1e-3c55346b5667 rw
```

but there's no  files in my `/` at all only the directories. Might that be the problem?

Comment: Where is your kernel and initrd?

Comment: I booted from my thumb drive, mounted my `/` (`/dev/sda4`) to `/mnt` and `chroot`ed to `/mnt` and a `# find / -name "initrd"` doesn't return a thing, that's a problem right there, isn't it?

Comment: Yep... Include details of your partitions etc in your question. And where is your ESP?

Comment: @jasonwryan I revised my question, please see above

Comment: @cerr Does your `/etc/fstab` file contain anything else or just that entry for `/dev/sda4`?

Comment: You need to mount your ESP to `/boot` and reinstall `linux` and then update your `arch.conf` and `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @sixpointzero no, there's nothing else in it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boot from your bootable USB Arch-linux , mount all your partitions and `chroot` into the system.

As montioned [jasonwryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6761/jasonwryan) :

> You need to mount your ESP to `/boot`

First create the `efi` folder:

```
mkdir /boot/efi
```

mount the `esp` partition

```
mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi
```

Verify your `/etc/fstab` , the `esp` mount point need to be added to `fstab`.

Create a new sub-directory `/boot/efi/EFI/arch/`

```
mkdir -p /boot/efi/EFI/arch/
```

Move `/boot/vmlinuz-linux` , `initramfs-linux.img` and `initramfs-linux-fallback.img` :

```
cp /boot/vmlinuz-linux /boot/efi/EFI/arch/vmlinuz-linux.efi
cp /boot/initramfs-linux.img /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img /boot/efi/EFI/arch
```

Run `mkinitcpio -p linux` then update GRUB:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

`

Comment: The EFI system partition is not always `/dev/sda1`. You need to run `fdisk -l` to know what it is

Answer (score 0):

The GAD3R answer may be applicable to grub, but not the systemd-boot you are using.  The problem appears to be simply that your UUID is 41d8... but your options specify PARTUUID, which would be a different ID.

The simple correction is in your arch.conf change the options to be root=UUID=41d... etc

The method is simple and works well.

NO problem with files or directories.  The referenced linux and initrd files should not be in your "/" ie 41d... partition at all.  They should be in the efi partition at the top level, not in a directory (with your version of arch.conf).  This is confusing, because the eg "linux" instruction instructs them to be found in "/", but this refers to the top level of the efi partition, and not the os partition.  With your efi partition mounted to an otherwise empty /boot directory in the os, you should see them (when rooted in the 41d... partition) as in the /boot directory.

Alternatively, if you might have different kernels for your different flavours of Arch, find the kernel version with uname -r then if this was 4.19.66-1-lts you mkdir /boot/4.19.66-1-lts then move those two files from /boot to /boot/4.19.66-1-lts , and change your particular arch.conf to read eg linux /4.19.66-1-lts/vmlinuz-linux

I have done this with mine, but have not yet had different kernels in place.