# How to install blackarch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

I have the latest blackarch ISO (2019). I have live-booted it on a 64-GB USB. The Live-Boot works perfectly. However, if I install it in my HDD, It boots in the GRUB Menu. 
Here is the steps I followed:
I used `blackarch-install` command.
Once I reached the query saying `install with windows/other OS?(y/n)?`
I put in `y` (though I tried with `n` too).
Then opens the partition menu. The partitions are as follows:

```
/dev/sda1:HPFS (where in my Windows resides)
/dev/sda2: (500M) Linux
/dev/sda3: (16G) Linux Swap/Solaris
/dev/sda4: (128G) Linux
```

Proceeding, I set the boot partition as /dev/sda2 and root as /dev/sda3 with both filesystems ext4 (I even tried with ext3 and ext2 for both and btrfs for root partition)
When I write this partition table and install it, the installer ends without any error even the grub-install returns no error

However, when it tells me to reboot, on reboot, it goes to the GRUB menu.
surprisingly, after installation, no initrd file shows up in the `/` or the `/boot` directory, though an `initramfs` is there (which when used dumps the kernel)

What am I doing wrong during the Installation?

solutions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311755/installed-arch-linux-but-cannot-boot) don't work :(

Comment: [Apparently](https://github.com/BlackArch/blackarch/issues/1965) `blackarch-install` does not support installation on a machine with UEFI firmware, which is the norm today. If you have UEFI firmware, you may be better off trying to install Arch Linux first and then install BalckArch on top of that, as described in the guide.

Comment: But my disk has Legacy support enabled. And the partition scheme is also MBR

Comment: Ok, I guess that's not the fault then. I said "if"...

Comment: @JohanMyréen There is no /boot/efi partition, so it's not EFI .

Comment: Oh sorry. But can you please help me with this? This is really getting on my nerves.

Comment: Is there, by any chance, any different software available out there to install blackarch Linux?

Comment: Even my grub.cfg appears to be alright